# How often has the ISS been physically vacant (un-manned)?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight

Currently six great folks are working in the International Space Station (ISS).  I am wondering if it is ever vacant and if there's a rule of thumb (magnitude of order of days, an average or anything) that it might be so.

**On a high level estimation, how frequently - if ever - is the ISS not manned *on board*?**

Comment: Please kindly note that I can't find the answer to whether it has happened (nobody inside the ISS) or not, so that's the odd tone of the question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_human_spaceflights_to_the_International_Space_Station), the ISS has been manned ever since the first crew of [Expedition 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expedition_1) entered on November 2nd 2000.

EDIT: As @Tristan pointed out the ISS was technically unmanned for a couple of times so far when there was just one crew on board which had to relocate the soyuz to another docking port, see comments below.

Comment: There have been brief excursions (only a few minutes) where nobody was technically on board.  These occurred between the departure of one increment crew and the launch of its replacement, where the crew was only at 3.  In these instances, they needed to move their Soyuz from one docking port to another.  All three were in the Soyuz during that transfer, with nobody on board the ISS.

Comment: Do you have an example of that happening?

Comment: October 10, 2006, with Soyuz TMA-9; November 18, 2005, with Soyuz TMA-7; March 20, 2006, with Soyuz TMA-7; July 19, 2005, with Soyuz TMA-6; November 29, 2004, with Soyuz TMA-5; April 18, 2001, with Soyuz TM-31; February 24, 2001, also with Soyuz TM-31

Comment: Wow great, thank you very much! Where di you find this information?

Comment: Pulled from Wikipedia to find all Soyuz flights that involved a relocation, then crosschecked ISS expedition information and other Soyuz and shuttle flights to make sure nobody else was there at the time.

Comment: Well I have a question, why not just send one person to relocate the Soyuz, while the rest wait in the station and join later?  Is it because of the time it takes in the connection?  And thanks for the added detail!

Comment: The reason for that is in case there is a problem and that person cannot redock the soyuz, the others would be left without a way to get back to earth. [(see here)](https://spaceflightnow.com/2015/08/28/soyuz-relocation-clears-way-for-launch-of-new-station-crew/) They actually prepare everything as if they'd leave the spacestation to go back to earth whenever they perform a relocatio maneuver.

Answer (score 4):

> Expedition-1 docked to ISS November 2, 2000. Since then ISS has been continuously occupied... *except* for brief periods when the crew undocked in order to relocate their Soyuz return vehicle from one docking port to another. Per the thread below on collectSPACE, ISS was left unoccupied for the following durations [mm:ss]:

```
Soyuz TM-31 ... 02/24/2001 ... [29:04]
Soyuz TM-31 ... 04/18/2001 ... [20:30]
Soyuz TM-32 ... 10/19/2001 ... [16:00]
Soyuz TM-33 ... 04/20/2002 ... [21:35]
Soyuz TMA-5 ... 11/29/2004 ... [20:48]
Soyuz TMA-6 ... 07/19/2005 ... [29:49]
Soyuz TMA-7 ... 11/18/2005 ... [19:38]
Soyuz TMA-7 ... 03/20/2006 ... [22:01]
Soyuz TMA-9 ... 10/10/2006 ... [20:10]
Soyuz TMA-9 ... 03/29/2007 ... [24:31]
Soyuz TMA-10 .. 09/27/2007 ... [27:10]
```

> Since then the ISS crew size has been expanded. There have been subsequent Soyuz port relocations (and will be future port relocations of Crew Dragon and Starliner) but none have left/will leave the station completely unoccupied. So the "true" start of permanent occupation of ISS was 9/27/2007.

[Collectspace Link](http://www.collectspace.com/ubb/Forum31/HTML/000548.html)

All quoted from rendezvous wizard Jorge Frank's Facebook post. (no link, private group)

Answer (score 4):

When the Space Shuttle was grounded after the *Columbia* accident, the ISS resident crew was reduced to two, to cut down on the consumables required. This lasted from 3 May 2003 to 6 July 2006 when it was restored to three. During this period, eleven EVAs were carried out, involving both astronauts, which meant that the ISS was technically unmanned while they were outside. The shortest of these lasted just fourteen minutes (cut short due to a spacesuit problem) while the longest was 6 hours 31 minutes.